# How "Blueprintable" make a class blueprintable?

Tags: unreal-engine4

According to UE4 class specifiers, "Blueprintable" can expose a C++ class to be base class of blueprint class. I'm confused in how this works?

Answer (score 2):

[Unreal Header Tool](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/BuildTools/UnrealHeaderTool/index.html) parses the `"Blueprintable"` metadata in the `UCLASS` macro and expands it to both `"IsBlueprintBase"` and `"BlueprintType"`.

In the editor, `FKismetEditorUtilities::CanCreateBlueprintOfClass(const UClass* Class)` checks the existence of the `"IsBlueprintBase"` (`FBlueprintMetadata::MD_IsBlueprintBase`) metadata on the `UClass` as one of the possible methods of determining if a class can be a base class for a blueprint.